# ASUS notebook hangs on shutdown with 14.04. Nvidia related...?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, shutdown, asus

When I attempt to shut down via the terminal or GUI (and even sometimes during startup), the computer hangs indefinitely and I have to hold the manual power button to turn off.

After much troubleshooting, it seems to have something to do with the NVIDIA graphics card. I'll sometimes see messages during start up with 'nouveau' in them (Ubuntu's default driver for NVIDIA?) but they scroll too fast to capture.

While trying to debug, I caused the system to hang by just entering in terminal

```
nvidia-detector
```

it returns `none` and then hangs. Any thoughts?

specs:

- ASUS k501LX-EB71
- NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 950M
- Ubuntu 14.04 dual-booted with Windows 10

things I've tried:

- Adding the `acpi=force` in `/etc/default/grub` and updating grub as many answers have suggested; along with other variations with `apm=power_off` and removing `quiet splash`. No effect.
- Observing the `shutdown` information with `sudo shutdown -v -P now`, but it hangs before anything is displayed and just freezes on the current screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might have posted a few minutes too soon, looks like I might have resolved it (at least it has shutdown properly 3 times a row and `nvidia-detector` doesn't hang the system). I want to leave the question up for others who run into this problem

I simply went to "Additional Drivers" in Dash and selected the Nvidia proprietary driver that was available:

NVIDIA binary driver - version 346.82 from nvidia-346 (proprietary, tested)

instead of the previously selected, non-proprietary driver:

X.Org X server - Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)

Note that I've left my /etc/default/grub with the line:

`GRUB_CMD_LINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=force apm=power_off"`